# For $x_n$ in A, prove that $\lim(x_n)$ is also in A.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let A, a subset of Reals be closed and let $x_n$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers with the following property: there exists N in naturals such that for all $n>N$ it holds that $x_n$ in A. Prove that $\lim(x_n)$ is also in A.
We know that $x_n$ being a convergent sequence means it is also bounded. So, if the elements of $x_n$ when n is big are in A, then $\lim(x_n)$ should be too. But how do we go around to prove that?

Comment: What's your definition of closed?

Comment: It means that it contains its boundary points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n$. Assume, on the contrary, $x \notin A$. Then $x \in A^c$. Since $A$ is closed, $A^c$ is open. And there exists a $\epsilon > 0$ so that $B_{\epsilon}(x)\equiv\{y\in R: \left\vert y-x \right\vert < \epsilon\} \subset A^c$. By definition of limit, there exists an $N$ so that for all $n > N$, $\vert x_n - x\vert < \epsilon$. Hence $x_n \in B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset A^c$, and $x_n \notin A$ for $n > N$. This contradicts with the condition that $x_n \in A$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful!

Comment: By () do you mean the epsilon neighbourhood?

Comment: yes, the epsilon neighborhood of $x$ with radius $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to prove it by contradiction.  Suppose the limit $L = \lim\limits_n x_n$ is not in $A$.  Since $A$ is closed, there is an interval containing $L$ which does not contain any point of $A$.  Why does this lead to a contradiction?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where the contradiction comes in. If A is closed, it means that it contains its boundary points. So, if L doesn't contain any point of A... what happens?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Let $x$ be the limit.  Then $x$ is a limit point of $A$, or else the sequence is eventually constant.

Comment: From there I can just say that since A is closed, it contains its limit points and so, contains x. But how do I prove that x is a limit point of A?

Comment: By definition,  unless the sequence is eventually constant.

Comment: If $A$ is just a point, then there are no limit points, for instance.